# creating a gzip file in memory looking for cpp example

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I am using the zlib to compress data but I need to create a valid gzip file with it in memory.

How do I correctly do that?

I need the file to be in memory but I'm not sure how to assemble it without writing to disk.

I have looked around but nothing clear cut stood out as a how to.

I know there's a gz_header but I'm not sure where the offset is in the file or how that's handled. Apparently there can be a trailer as well?

Comment: Side suggestion: You have asked a lot of questions and accepted none of them. Try going over your questions, see which actually answered what you wanted and accept those answers.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize it. I have marked the ones I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Boost.Iostream with Gzip filters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html) to compress data. You can adapt the example to use a memory stream instead of a file stream.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use their library. I've attempted to "include core components" hpp files and i'm getting a lot of strange errors with my make file. I would think I need to build their library and not just include headers into mine to use these features.

Comment: I'm getting this error: error: ‘filtering_streambuf’ was not declared in this scope. I am just copying their example and including the folder via my makefile. The code I'm changing is ancient legacy c++ so I'm not sure if I can even recursively tell it check sub folders for include files.

Comment: using namespace boost::iostreams; // Added this line. 
    
fixed the error. now on to figuring out how to use their library

Comment: Congratulations on deciding to use Boost. You've made a step toward better C++ code. Enjoy!